# NSManagedObject and Codable for class stored in server and local storage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, codable

I am creating a class that represents data that is either in local storage or comes in from online. On runtime I will use a get request to get an array of these objects from a server and compare them to the existing ones in CoreData in order to determine a new set of objects to be used for the app and to be stored.

As such I have created a CoreData managed class that represents my object as such it inherits `NSManagedObject`. This will allow me to deal with the local storage getting the array in storage and putting back a new one after the app has finished.

I would then like to make this class Codable that way I can implement the `required public init(from decoder: Decoder)` method that allows me to get my array of objects like this in the get request. `JSONDecoder().decode([DataClass].self, from: data!)`.

There are two ways I am trying to do this and neither of them are working.

**Problems:**

I have a `private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {...}` in class scope and using that to encode works great but for whatever reason that triggers an error that says that the class doesn't implement encode which I have no intention of implementing. I am not sure why that matters.

I can put the enum inside the scope of the initializer but if I do that a new problem pops up. I must call a designated initializer of `NSManagedObject`. This is a problem because that call requires a `NSManagedObjectContext` which I dont have.

**As an alternative:**

I have create a method `func getDataClass(from decoder: Decoder) -> DataClass?` however this also brings with it two problems. I still must initialize a `DataClass` object somehow and I have no clue how to bring that into the `JSONDecoder().decode([DataClass].self, from: data!)` line.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make `DataClass` conform to `Codable`.

First of all create two extensions to be able to pass the `NSManagedObjectContext` in the `userInfo` dictionary of the `JSONDecoder`.

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")!
}

extension JSONDecoder {
    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.init()
        self.userInfo[.context] = context
    }
}
```

---

The following example uses only one attribute `name` in `DataClass`.
The `Codable` methods must be in the class not in the *CoreDataProperties* extension.

```
class DataClass: NSManagedObject, Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    }

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.context] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError("Error: NSManagedObject not specified!") }
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "DataClass", in: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

To use the decoder you have to use the initializer

```
let context = // get the managed object context
let decoder = JSONDecoder(context: context)
```

Comment: This is a great solution! But I am a bit confused. When we grab the entity and context we aren't actually using them or changing anything about them right? This is just a work around.

Comment: With this code you can create Core Data records from JSON  and create JSON from Core Data records. If you don't need the latter change the conformance to `Decodable` and delete `encode(to encoder`

Comment: WIthout that method I get an error saying the class does not conform to Decodable. It is like that is a subclass of NSManagedObject or Codable

Comment: And I still need the context and entity in order to use the designated initalizer

Comment: What if `DataClass` has an attribute member that is of type `[String]` or `[Int]`, how do we encode those attributes? That is, we need to specify `case ArrayOfStrings` and/or `case ArrayOfInts`.