# How to Store and Fetch Json Model data to Coredata in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, structure

I have used coredata long back. But, I know basics of coredata for storing data and fetching.

But, Presently I am working with Swift language.

I have local json file and I am doing parsing that by decoder and displaying that data in tableview.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "json")

do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path ?? ""), options: .mappedIfSafe)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        quData = try decoder.decode(quData.self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Json decoder error")
    }
} catch {
    print(LocalizedError.self)
}
```

For that I have created model class based on the key values of json.

But, Now I have to store that data to Coredata and Fetch back, Need to show in same tableview.

But, I am getting confusion how many key values should I need to create.

My model class is :

```
class QuData: Codable {
    let qu: Qu

    init(qu: Qu) {
        self.qu = qu
    }
}

class Qu: Codable {
    let music: Music
    let dance: dance

    init(music: Music, dance: dance) {
        self.music = music
        self.dance = dance
    }
}

class Maths: Codable {
    let q1, q2: Q1

    init(q1: Q1, q2: Q1) {
        self.q1 = q1
        self.q2 = q2
    }
}

class Q1: Codable {
    let query: String
    let options: [String]
    let answer: String
    let q1Optional: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case query, options, answer
        case q1Optional = "optional"
    }

    init(question: String, options: [String], answer: String, q1Optional: Bool) {
        self.query = query
        self.options = options
        self.answer = answer
        self.q1Optional = q1Optional
    }
}

class Sport: Codable {
    let q1: Q1

    init(q1: Q1) {
        self.q1 = q1
    }
}
```

And my JSON data is

```
{
    "qu": {
        "music": {
            "q1": {
                “query”: “What is your name?”,
                "options": [
                    “Sony”,
                    “Samsung”,
                    “Apple”,
                    “MI”
                ],
                "answer": “Apple”,
                "optional": true

            }
        },
        “dance”: {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 1 = ?",
                "options": [
                    “8”,
                    “9”,
                    “6”,
                    “23”
                ],
                "answer": “23”,
                "optional": false
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 4 = ?",
                "options": [
                    “5”,
                    “4”,
                    “9”,
                    “6”
                ],
                "answer": "4",
                "optional": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to store these data to Coredata and fetching, Showing in tableview..

And, The two categories (music,dance) in json data, I have to show "Music" data in 1st section and "Dance" data in
section tableview.

I am fully struck, how to create this kind json structure in Entity with attributes and fetching them using same model class (Which already created for local json file parsing).

Can anyone suggest me to move on further?

Comment: @iPeter any suggestion for this?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459182/nsmanagedobject-and-codable-for-class-stored-in-server-and-local-storage/52459426#52459426. By the way you can delete all `init` methods. `Codable` synthesizes the initializers.

Comment: @vadian How to create/declare attributes according to that json structure?

Comment: This is a bit tricky because you have to consider the relationships. Basically a struct/class correspond to an entity.

Comment: If possible, Can you post your answer according to my query, else can you provide any reference to create this json structure in entity and fetch back data.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use **one** entity.

In Core Data you can filter records very efficiently, so add a `type` attribute representing `music`, `dance` etc. You can even add a computed property to map the `type` attribute to an enum. The `options` attribute is declared as flat string. Use another computed property to map the flat string to an array and vice versa.

```
class Question : NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var type: String
    @NSManaged var question: String
    @NSManaged var answer: String
    @NSManaged var options: String
    @NSManaged var optional: Bool

    enum QuestionType : String {
        case music, dance
    }

    var questionType : QuestionType {
        get { return QuestionType(rawValue: type)! }
        set { type = newValue.rawValue }
    }

    var questionOptions : [String] {
        get { return options.components(separatedBy: ", ") }
        set { options = newValue.joined(separator: ", ") }
    }
```

---

Alternatively use one entity per type and relationships for the questions

```
class Music : NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var questions: Set<Question>

    ...
}


class Question : NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var question: String
    @NSManaged var answer: String
    @NSManaged var options: String
    @NSManaged var optional: Bool

    @NSManaged var type: Music

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions, Acutally I have only basic idea about coredata like storing just user data and fetching, But, These kind relationships I have no idea, But, I am looking for storing the complete model class to coredata from json response and fetching that data back to assign to same model class to display in tableview.

Comment: Please read the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)

Comment: Really thanks so much for your quick response. So, Do I need to create 2 entities and attributes? And how can I assign the model data directly to these attributes like setvalues or is there any better approach to assign complete data model to coredata?

Comment: You don't *need* to create two entities. Use a model which fits your needs at its best.  If the data comes from a file in the bundle and won't be changed I doubt that you need Core Data at all. The way to create NSManagedObject instances from JSON data is described in the linked answer of my first comment

Comment: But, How to insert data form model class to coredata according to your code?

Comment: As the `NSManagedObject` conforms to `Codable` you can *decode* directly into the class(es).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180714/discussion-between-anilkumar-ios-developer-and-vadian).